# JWPlayer unable play videos on ChromeCast

Tags: web, mp4, jwplayer, chromecast, jwplayer6

I'm using latest JWPlayer(6.9) which was recently released. I'm using JWPlayer Javascript API for playing MP4 videos, It works perfectly well on Chrome/Firefox but the same code was pushed on ChromeCast and JWPlayer was unable to load/play the MP4 video.

Is their any way or any solution were I can load MP4 Videos using JWPLayer on ChromeCast device.

Also how can I send a playlist to JWPlayer in ChromeCast.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the JW Player supports this, as long as your edition is Ads or Enterprise - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1611909-embedding-with-chromecast

Comment: Thanks for the reply. JWPlayer is not providing any control over JWPlayer playback. It has it own URL which is to be placed on Google ChromeCast portal application and casted to the same URL. I'm looking for an way to load MP4 video using JWPlayer's Javascript API.

Comment: You can still use our API and use Chromecast.

Comment: Ok, provide a link then.